# How to write (manually added) GPS coordinates to originals in Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture

I'm using Aperture to add GPS coordinates to photos I've taken. The original stills are in craw2 and movies are in mov file format.

I've noticed when I export originals that the photos didn't retain the GPS coordinates that were added. Exporting versions did retain the GPS coordinates.

How do I ensure GPS coordinates can be saved to the original craw and mov files?

I've read [Can places be assigned to a whole folder (and subfolders) in aperture 3?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/can-places-be-assigned-to-a-whole-folder-and-subfolders-in-aperture-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can read this isn't currently possible without the help of a 3rd party plugin.

The "Metadata > Write IPTC Metadata to Original" command within Aperture is the closest I can find but the definition that Aperture 3 uses for IPTC metadata does not include GPS information unfortunately.

There's more discussion on this in Apple's discussion forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2370910?start=0&tstart=0) (There are other useful discussions but I'm currently unable to post more than two links in this reply)

The 3rd party plugin that referenced on those pages (Ubermind's MapaturePro which is no longer currently available) can be downloaded [here](http://download.cnet.com/Maperture-Pro/3001-12511_4-75000925.html?spi=bf69a9ca791ea376bc1a1feb56861d0b) although I was unable to install it past it's registration step unfortunately, presumably because it was unable to contact Ubermind's now offline servers to complete registration.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I really appreciate your help and tips on this. I too noticed the IPTC metadata written to original doesn't have GPS.